# Visual C++ : XGBoost does not work when called from a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, xgboost

I have a requirement to use XGBoost within a Visual C++ project DLL.
I have been able to download and build the XGBoost source using VC++ and CMake.

When I include the XGBoost code in a test console application, it works fine.

However, when I try to replicate what I've done with the console application in a DLL project, it won't compile.
I am struggling to even use a basic XGBoost type within the project.

I suspect the problem is my ignorance with DLL projects and would appreciate your help.

Here's what's happening in my DLL project:
When I use the following include as the very first line in a cpp class file, it compiles:
`#include <xgboost\c_api.h>`

With it compiling, if I try to use a simple type defined in this include file, the build fails with the following message:
**...\dll_test\xgb_driver.cpp(20): error C2065: 'BoosterHandle': undeclared identifier**

This is the line that causes the error:
`BoosterHandle my_handle;`

"BoosterHandle" is in fact defined in `<xgboost\c_api.h>`

When I put the include below any other include, I get the following error messages:

**1>c:\tools\src\xgboost\include\xgboost\c_api.h(29): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int**

1>c:\tools\src\xgboost\include\xgboost\c_api.h(29): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'bst_ulong'

Below is a little more information on what I did to get XGBoost working with a console app and how I created the DLL project.

=-=-=-=-=-=

Here's what I did to use XGBoost with a console. Everything about it seems to work. I've tested the model predictions, and they are 
consistent with what I'm seeing in R.

Using the documentation found here:
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

1. I downloaded the XGBoost source and built it using CMake and Visual Studio 2015.
2. Under Project > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, 
   I added the xgboost.lib file
3. Under Project > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories
   I added a reference to ...\xgboost\build\Release
4. Under Project > VC++ Directories > Include Directories
   I added the path to ...\xgboost\rabit\include and ...\xgboost\include
5. I put the xgboost.dll in the directory where the .exe is generated.

From here, it was smooth sailing.

=-=-=-=-=-=

Here's what I've done to create a Visual C++ DLL Project:

After choosing File > New > Project, I select an ATL DLL Project (this is part of the project requirement).

For the XGBoost include to the project, I repeated steps 1-5 above, but placed the xgboost.dll file where the
project DLL would be generated.

Here is the source for the header file for the simple class I have created:

```
#pragma once
class XGB_Driver
{
public:
    XGB_Driver();
    ~XGB_Driver();

    float callXGB(float sample_input);
};
```

Here is the source for the simple cpp file:

```
#include <xgboost/c_api.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "XGB_Driver.h"


XGB_Driver::XGB_Driver()
{
}

XGB_Driver::~XGB_Driver()
{
}

float XGB_Driver::callXGB(float simple_input) {
    BoosterHandle my_handle;
    return(0);
}
```

Why this doesn't work for the ATL DLL project, but does for the console app really has me banging my head against the keyboard.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Best,
Dave

Comment: What happens if you `#include <cstdint>` **before** `#include <xgboost/c_api.h>`? Or better, if you move `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of the `#include`s list?

Comment: CristiFati, the #include <cstdint> addition before the xgboost header seems to have solved the problem. I am not sure why this was needed in a DLL project, but not a console project, but hey, I'll take it.    I would like to give you credit for the answer, but my options are to either add a comment or answer my own question. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What about moving the `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top? If that alone doesn't work, then `#include <cstdint>` should be placed in *StdAfx.h*. This is how it should be done. Let me know if it works for you, and then I'll post an answer with explanations and everything.

Comment: It works, if you have details as to why it works, I would be very grateful.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't understand the errors in the 1st part of the question, and building *xgboost* is an overhead too big for me at this point. So, go ahead and answer your own question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to assist. I will answer the question.

Comment: NP. Make sure to also mark your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of CristiFati, I believe this question has been answered.
For whatever reason, it seems that using XGBoost with C++ in a DLL project requires additional includes above and beyond what is required for using it in a console application.
I am currently building the DLL project with the addition of: 
`#include <cstdint>`